# Could not get the nested array initialization work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am puzzled by this behavior

```
r,c = (5,2)
slist = [[0]*c]*r
print(slist)

for i in range(r):
    slist[i][0] = i
print(slist)
```

Output is

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0]]
```

Comment: How are you puzzled by this behaviour?

Comment: May be I am losing my mind. I wanted to assign (0,0)-th element to 0, (1,0)-th element to 1, (2,0)-th element to 2, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `[[0] * c] * r`, you create a list where every element is a reference to the **same list**. So, when you change one, they all change. Use a list comprehension with a range instead to create unique lists:

```py
slist = [[0] * c for _ in range(r)]
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29785158/5923139) for more info.