# Why is python appending two variables instead of one?

Tags: python, list

```
class PokerGame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Cards = [['A', 'Q'], ['K', '10']]
        self.Hands = []


    def Play(self):
        print(self.Hands) # []
        print(self.Cards) # [['A', 'Q'], ['K', '10']]
        for x in self.Cards:
            self.Hands.append(x) 
        print(self.Hands) # [['A', 'Q'], ['K', '10']]
        print(self.Cards) # [['A', 'Q'], ['K', '10']]
        self.Hands[0].append("KKK")
        print(self.Hands) # [['A', 'Q', 'KKK'], ['K', '10']]
        print(self.Cards) # [['A', 'Q', 'KKK'], ['K', '10']]???

b = PokerGame()
b.Play()
```

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve]. Almost assuredly, though, it's because both variables are referring to *the same object*

Comment: Why does this have the dictionary tag?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785084/changing-one-list-unexpectedly-changes-another-too) answer your question?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych It didn't help. I'm getting the same result. I changed the code to be reproducible. Can you please check if you can help? Thanks.

Comment: As per @quamrana's answer and answers in the link I've posted, you need to deep-copy your list when appending. I.E. `self.Hands.append(x[:])` or `self.Hands.append(list(x))` .

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Deep copy worked. Thanks so much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is my reproduction of the problem:

```py
Cards = [['10S', '9S'], ['5H', 'JD']]
Hands = []
for x in Cards:
    Hands.append(x)
print(Hands) # -  ([['10S', '9S'], ['5H', 'JD']])
print(Cards) # - ([['10S', '9S'], ['5H', 'JD']])
Hands[0].append("KKK")
print(Hands) # - [['10S', '9S', 'KKK'], ['5H', 'JD']]
print(Cards) # - [['10S', '9S', 'KKK'], ['5H', 'JD']] ????
```

Its simply that: `Hands.append(x)` is not copying anything, its just adding references.

Compare the above to the below:

```py
Cards = [['10S', '9S'], ['5H', 'JD']]
Hands = []
for x in Cards:
    Hands.append(x[:])   # Here is a copy
print(Hands) # -  ([['10S', '9S'], ['5H', 'JD']])
print(Cards) # - ([['10S', '9S'], ['5H', 'JD']])
Hands[0].append("KKK")
print(Hands) # - [['10S', '9S', 'KKK'], ['5H', 'JD']]
print(Cards) # - [['10S', '9S'], ['5H', 'JD']]
```

Comment: Same with me but when I do the same in class form, both Hands and Cards are being appended by the KKK item. I can't understand why for the life of me.

Comment: So you need a way of making copies of your instances.

Comment: I fixed the code to be reproducible. Can you please check if you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Deep copy fixed it. Suggestion from @Yevhen Kuzmovych. Thanks so much also.