# Assignment of variable to list using indexing

Tags: python, list

The following is a simple function:

```
def func(first):
         third = first[0]
         first[0][0] = 5
         print(third)

first = [[3,4]]
func(first)
```

I was expecting the output to be [3,4] but instead, it's supposed to be [5,4]. I thought that during the assignment of the variable "third" in the first line, the right-hand side of "first[0]" had already been evaluated to give [3,4] and thus, third would stay as this value for the rest of the function execution steps.

Edit:

I now understand why the above function works the way it does. The variable `third` references the list within `first` and thus, when that changes, `third` will also change. I now have one more question:

What about referencing a slice of a list, instead of a specific index?

```
def func(first):
         third = first[0][0:2]
         first[0][0] = 5
         print(third)

first = [[3,4]]
func(first)
```

Does this method of referencing now create a new list that `third` is referenced to?

Comment: The output is [3,4] though? Where did [5,4] come frm

Comment: @ AnikethMalyala @GinoMempin pls see edited qn

Comment: It's a duplicate of [Changing one list unexpectedly changes another, too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29785084/2745495) or the more general [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/2745495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads:

```py
def func(first):
         third = first[0]
         first[0][0] = 5
         print(third)

first = [[3,4]]
func(first)
```

What's happening is this:

- In `func()`, the argument `first` contains a reference to a list of lists with value `[[3,4]]`.
- After the assignment to `third`, `third` contains a reference to the list `[3,4]` at position 0  in the list referenced by `first`. No new list object has been created and no copy of a list has taken place, rather a new reference to the existing list has been created and stored in the variable `third`.
- In the line `first[0][0] = 5`, the item at position 0 in the list `[3,4]` is updated so that the list is now `[5,4]`. Note that the list `[3,4]` that was modified is an element of the list of lists referenced by `first`, and it is also the one referenced by `third`. Because the object (namely, the list) that is referenced by `third` has now been modified, any use of this reference to access the list (such as `print(third)`) will reflect its updated value, which is `[5,4]`.

**UPDATE:**

The code for your updated question is:

```py
def func(first):
         third = first[0][0:2]
         first[0][0] = 5
         print(third)

first = [[3,4]]
func(first)
```

In this case, the assignment `third = first[0][0:2]` takes a slice of the list `[3,4]` at position 0 in the list of lists referenced by `first`. Taking a slice in this way creates a new object which is a copy of the subsequence indicated by the arguments specified in the square brackets, so after the assignment, the variable `third` contains a reference to a newly created list with value `[3,4]`. The subsequent assignment `first[0][0] = 5` updates the value of the list `[3,4]` in position 0 of the list of lists referenced by `first`, with the result that the value of the list becomes `[5,4]`, and has no effect on the value of `third` which is an independent object with value `[3,4]`.

Importantly (and potentially confusingly), slice notation used on the left-hand side of an assignment works very differently. For example, `first[0][0:2] = [5,4]` would change the contents of the list `first[0]` such that the elements in index 0 and 1 are replaced by `[5,4]` (which in this case means the value of the list object would be changed from `[3,4]` to `[5,4]`, but it would be the same object).

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my qn again to reflect an additional query

Comment: Please see the second part of my updated answer which addresses your additional query.

Comment: It's interesting that slicing creates new objects while just assigning or indexing does not.

Comment: Focus on the concept of `mutability` or `immutability` of the data types with which you are working. integer, float are immutable. Assigning the name means assigning the name to a memory location that contains that value. Python binds/connects the integer. float to a location that contains that value. Take the `lyst = [1,2,3]` of integers. Now enter`x=1, y=2 z=3`.
`id(lyst[0]) == id(x), id(lyst[1]) == id(y),  id(lyst[2) == id(z)` will all be `True` because python looks for an immutable value that already exists and binds the name to it.

Answer (score 1):

A variable identifies a memory location. If the contents of the memory location is mutable like a list, the contents are changed by code. All names that identify that location will reflect the change. If the contents are immutable like an integer the name will be assigned a new memory location.  `x = 5` `y =5`,  `x` and `y` point to the same memory location. `x = 6` `y` will still point to the location containing `5`. `x` will point to the location containing `6`.

```
def func(first):
    third = first[0]
    print(f'{id(first[0])=}  {id(third)=}')  # They are the same list. 
    # Name points to same address. So changing contents of memory.
    first[0][0] = 5
    print(third)


first = [[3, 4]]
func(first)
```

Output

```
id(first[0])=2652914318144  id(third)=2652914318144
[5, 4]
```

Comment: Sorry, pls see edited qn

Comment: Yes, but I am curious why that is the output, because I thought third is assigned to [3,4] in the first line of the function

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question again. Pls take a look thanks so much!

Comment: Does this method of referencing now create a new list that third is referenced to? Yes it creates a new list. Remember you can always check in several ways besides id you can use `list1 is list2`. That will be true if they are names pointing to the same location. `list1 == list2` would not be a good test to see if they point to the same location. It would be true if they are lists stored in different locations but have exactly the same contents,