# Indirectly Changing Variables in Python

Tags: python, variable-assignment, fenics

I'm currently working through the following FEniCS tutorial program [Heat Equation Tutorial](https://jsdokken.com/dolfinx-tutorial/chapter2/diffusion_code.html). In the program, the following block of code appears initializing the variables L, linear_form and b.

```
L = (u_n + dt * f) * v * ufl.dx
linear_form = fem.form(L)
b = create_vector(linear_form)
```

later in the program, we have the following block of code -

```
for i in range(num_steps):
    t += dt

    # Update the right hand side reusing the initial vector
    with b.localForm() as loc_b:
        loc_b.set(0)
    assemble_vector(b, linear_form)
.
.
.
# Update solution at previous time step (u_n)
    u_n.x.array[:] = uh.x.array
```

I'm not sure how, but in every iteration of the for loop, the variable L is updated (presumably due to u_n being updated. My question is the following - how does this occur? Given a variable x defined in terms of another, y, under what circumstances can changing y cause x to change as well?

I know this is probably a very basic question, I'm a mathematician and new to Python.

As a side question, if anyone can refer me to a section in a text where this is treated more thoroughly, please send it my way

Comment: The short answer, without explaining the actual implemantion of the library, is that things like `v` are implicitly functions (or rather, objects that represent functions, not actual Python `function` objects), so `v * ufl.dx`, for example, is not a value at a particular time, but itself a function of time.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785084/changing-one-list-unexpectedly-changes-another-too and see if that answers your question.